# How to send data with html file from Express server

Tags: express, server, client

Currently, I'm making two round trips to my server.  The first trip is to send the html file to my client via `res.sendFile()`.  Once that html file is loaded in the client, I need to fetch the data for that page, so I have to make a second request to the server (sometimes using an IIFE to get the data immediately on page load), where I send the data back via `res.send()` or `res.json()`.

From what I've read, it's not possible to do all of this in one step, so are two round trips to the server the best way (or only way) to render an html file and its data in the client?

The only other option I know of is to use a templating engine like Handlebars or EJS, but I don't think either one can handle the complex logic I need in the client. I tried Handlebars once, and the client logic was a mess.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fill your HTML page with dynamic data there are no other options to use a template engine if you want just one trip to your server.

For me using PUG template engine (formerly Jade) was good enough.

Comment: Yes, PUG is another option.  Are two round-trips standard then for single page applications?

Comment: Yes. All of them sends more requests to fetch necessary data. Nothing is wrong about it.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.  Thank you.